# Potential conflict between a Dialog and Back button

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

I nailed down a weird behavior on JQM.

Since the page is based on JQM Boiler plate, I do not include the full page here.  I published the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alain_lavoie/jEesE/).

Here is a summary of the behavior click actions:

[image: (Windows sequence between click)]

Here is the extract of the relevant code:

```
<div id="oneapart" 
    data-add-back-btn="true" 
    data-back-btn-text="List" 
    data-role="page" 
    data-title="Home page">
```

I do not understand why the last click on the List button (a jquery mobile back button) requires 2 click to actually act on the  link.  In fact, the weird behavior is that a first click highlight the button in blue, but it remains as is without switching to the previous page until a second click happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Corrected, thanks for your patience.

Comment: It's working fine for me on my desktop Chrome browser and on my android 2.3 phone browser, so, what browser are you using?

Comment: It needs 2 click to make the List work on chrome (iMac, Win7), on Safari (iphone, ipad, on the original website).  You can reproduce it on a desktop.

Comment: I am about to add comments on the drawing to clearly show the necessary step to reproduce the effect.

Comment: It does behave like this also on Firefox (iMac Lion and Win7).

Comment: Ah ok, now I can reproduce it too.

Comment: It seems like a jquerymobile bug, I tested your fiddle with nightly jquerymobile and the bug persists, so you should file an issue in jquerymobile bug tracker, if you do it post the link here, as I might want to give it a go..

Comment: ok, I never did issue a bug on jqm, I will do so.

Comment: bug issued and linked to the question.

Comment: post the link here so I can check it out tomorrow

Comment: Here is the link for this jqm bug issue: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by adding the `data-rel="back"` to the button in the popup.

The [issue posted on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5224#issuecomment-9903172) has been marked as resolved because of that.

> The issue happens because `data-rel="back"` is missing in the link of the large cancel button in @jerone his fiddle. See "Closing dialogs" here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dialog/index.html
>
> The back button on pageTwo is dynamically created. When you don't use `data-rel="back"` on the link that brings you back from dialogThree (which is also a page) to pageTwo it adds an item to the history stack. That's why the back button on pageTwo then requires two clicks to actually bring you back to pageOne.
>   The active state is removed from a (back) button on the pagehide event. On the first click you stay on the same page, so this event doesn't fire and the button keeps the active state.
>
> I added `data-rel="back"` and then everything works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/jEesE/6/
>
> Closing as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The bug you're describing consists of 2 parts;

1. why does it require two clicks to revert?
2. why stays the button active (blue)?

The first part of the bug is not a bug; you open a popup, but instead of going back (e.g. `data-rel='back'` you open a page that is the same as the previous one. So if you press the back button, it reopens the previous page that is actually the same page as you were on right now (if it make sense).

Why the button stays active, I don't know...

*EDIT*: I cleaned up your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/jerone/jEesE/3/

Comment: I +1 your answer; thanks, meanwhile, I wish to keep the issue open since I still have the blue button.